# paypal pay now and returned variables

Tags: database, paypal-ipn

I am making a paypal pay now button for my website to add credits that can be used.

I understand the whole buy now and ipn thing but I what I would like to do is that when the user finishes his pay, there should be a way for the IPN to get the username so that I could add the credits into the database.

Is there a way to have the username sent together with the transaction so that it is returned, too? Thank you.

Comment: I recommend you use the encrypted button and configure PayPal to only accept encrypted requests. It's a bit hard to do, but worth it. What you are aiming at is making sure people cannot fake payments with using lesser amounts.

Comment: You should also implement the ping back in the IPN to check if PayPal recognizez the params you just received. Tutorial here: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNImplementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the button params, set the `notify_url` variable to an URL of maximum 255 characters.

PayPal will HTTP POST to this URL with the IPN details (`payment_status`, `payment_date`, etc.).

When creating the button, add params to this URL, such as http://yourwebsite.com?username_for_credits=john%20doe
.
When PayPal will make the IPN HTTP POST, you will get back the username you want.

Comment: If this is how you are using paypal, please consider reading my answer and using the "custom" parameter.

Comment: For myself, I am setting an id for the transaction which I store when I first create the button (along with other transaction related stuff). I have too much data to fit in that custom field.

Answer (score 1):

**Please do not rely on the notify url.**

You can send a 'custom' parameter in your dictionary object to paypal as listed in the [Paypal IPN Docs](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_IPNandPDTVariables).

```
paypal_dict = {
    "business": "yourpaypalemail@example.com",
    "amount": "10000000.00",
    "item_name": "name of the item",
    "invoice": "unique-invoice-id",
    "notify_url": "http://www.example.com/your-ipn-location/",
    "return_url": "http://www.example.com/your-return-location/",
    "cancel_return": "http://www.example.com/your-cancel-location/",
    "custom": request.user.username, #or you can use request.user.pk
}
```

**The 'custom' value will be saved on paypal's server with the transaction and in your IPN object**. This is a much better option than having payments with no customer identified.